# Angular 5 ngModel setting default value based on form input

Tags: angular, forms, firebase-realtime-database, form-control, ngmodel

I have an app built in Angular 5 using Firebase's Real Time Database. My form is using ngModel and has a user id field and a custom username field. I need the username to have a default value of the user id unless the user chooses to change it.

```
<label class="label-control" for="idInput">User Name</label>
<input id="userId" type="text" for="idInput" class="form-control"
       required minlength="1" name="userId"
       [(ngModel)]="userData.userId"
       #userId="ngModel"
       placeholder="e.g. johnhancock1776"
       />

<label class="label-control" for="vanityInput">Your Custom URL</label>
<input id="vanityId" type="text"
       for="vanityInput" 
       class="form-control"
       name="vanityId"
       [(ngModel)]="userData.vanityId"
       value="{{userData.userId}}"
       #vanityId="ngModel"
       placeholder="custom url" />
```

When the user puts In their user id the vanity id field populates but won't send data to the database unless they add or delete something from the vanity field.

I tried adding:

```
       [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'submit'}"
```

to the vanity field witch lets it send an empty string if neither field is touched, but won't send anything when only the user id is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a `(ngModelChange)` event to change the value of `userData.vanityId` instead of `value="{{userData.userId}}"` because you only change the view and not userData.vanityId value.

component.html

```
<label class="label-control" for="idInput">User Name</label>
<input id="userId" type="text" for="idInput" class="form-control"
       required minlength="1" name="userId"
       [(ngModel)]="userData.userId"
       #userId="ngModel"
       placeholder="e.g. johnhancock1776"
       (ngModelChange)="changeVanityId($event)"
       />
<br>
<label class="label-control" for="vanityInput">Your Custom URL</label>
<input id="vanityId" type="text"
       for="vanityInput" 
       class="form-control"
       name="vanityId"
       [(ngModel)]="userData.vanityId"
       #vanityId="ngModel"
       placeholder="custom url" />

<button (click)="sendBackend()">Send</button>
```

I added a button to print the userData value to verify that print the correct value.

component.ts

```
  /**
   * Print in console
   */
  sendBackend() {
    console.log(this.userData);
  } 

  /**
   * Change value of vanityId
   */
  changeVanityId(event) {
    this.userData.vanityId = event
  }
```

I implement this here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sadk7e